# Signing certificate doesn't import on keychain with GitHub Actions iOS distribution

Tags: ios, github-actions, keychain, cicd

I'm trying to Github Action for iOS app distribution and I have followed the official Github Action guideline - [Imports the Apple certificate and provisioning profile from the GitHub secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development#add-a-step-to-your-workflow)

But my archive failed at some point and I found that the signing certification doesn't get added to the keychain as a codesigning certificate.

```
security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH
```

Returns "`1 identity imported.`"

But when I check codesigning certificates

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning $KEYCHAIN_PATH
```

Returns "`0 valid identities found`"

Here is my complete code for the GitHub action

```
name: iOS build and TestFlight upload
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/temp
jobs:
  Build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, macOS]
    steps:
    - name: Xcode 14.3.1
      run: sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: "zulu"
        java-version: 17
        
    - name: Install the Apple certificate and provisioning profile
      env:
        BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 }}
        P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}
        BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64 }}
        KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
      run: |
        # create variables
        CERTIFICATE_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_certificate.p12
        PP_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_pp.mobileprovision
        KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db

        # import certificate and provisioning profile from secrets
        echo -n "$BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64" | base64 --decode -o $CERTIFICATE_PATH
        echo -n "$BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64" | base64 --decode -o $PP_PATH

        # check if the files exist
        ls $CERTIFICATE_PATH
        ls $PP_PATH
      
        # create temporary keychain          
        security create-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
        security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
        security unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH

        # keychain information and unlocked
        security show-keychain-info $KEYCHAIN_PATH

        # import certificate to keychain
        security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
        security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH
    
        # checking the validity of the codesigning identities
        security find-identity -v -p codesigning $KEYCHAIN_PATH

        # check if the certificate was added
        security find-certificate -a -p -c $CERTIFICATE_PATH $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      
        # apply provisioning profile
        mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
        cp $PP_PATH ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

        # check if the provisioning profile was added
        ls ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
      
    - name: Build archive
      run: | 
          xcodebuild -scheme XYZProject \
          -project $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/iosApp/XYXProject.xcodeproj \
          -archivePath $RUNNER_TEMP/XYZProject.xcarchive \
          -sdk iphoneos \
          -configuration Release \
          -destination generic/platform=iOS \
          clean archive
      
    - name: Clean up keychain and provisioning profile
      if: ${{ always() }}
      run: |
        security delete-keychain $RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db
        rm ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/build_pp.mobileprovision
```

Please note that this issue occurs when running on `[self-hosted, macOS]` and works fine on `macos-latest` github envirenment.
Any idea why and how to solve this issue?